# Adding Object Values Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so that Javascript automatically totals the prices of the items in the inventory together and also displays the total number of items in the inventory. I would have to make it so thatt it works for any amount added to the inventory. This is what I have so far. Thanks

```
function inventory (a,b,c)
{
this.name = a;
this.price = b;
this.id = c;


var item1 = new item ("Pen", 2.50,"001");
var item2 = new item ('Pencil', 1.25, '002');
var item3 = new item ('Paper', 0.75, '003');
}
```

Comment: Are you just calling `new` without really knowing what it does, or do you actually have a class named `item` ?

Comment: Without really knowing what it does.

Comment: Use arrays: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Comment: I would suggest you give [JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) a read, it will give you a good idea of the different ways you can structure your JavaScript to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but you can do something like this if you want it bound as an object property...

```
var Inventory = {
    "items" : [
        { "name" : "paperclip", "price" : 25 },
        { "name" : "folder", "price" : 350 },
        { "name" : "desk", "price" : 2999 }
    ],
    "total" : function totalItems() {
        var total = 0;
        this.items.forEach(function(item) {
            total += item.price;
        });
        return total;
    }
};

console.log( Inventory.total() ); // 3275
console.log( Inventory.items.length ) // 3, # items
```

Comment: No problem.  You really should give that design pattern book a small read, it will help you to use JS in a more OOP approach.

Comment: Using reduce to calculate the total woul be slightly more elegant ;). `this.items.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.price + b.price; });`

Comment: @plalx Thanks, never heard of/ used reduce before.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a library like Underscore or Lodash. They provide a lot of utility functions for operating on arrays, collections, and objects.

Specifically, check out the reduce() function: http://underscorejs.org/#reduce

So if you have an array of items, to get the sum of their prices all you'd have to do is:

```
var sum = _.reduce(items, function(total, item){return total + item.price;}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// By convention, class names should begin with an uppercase letter
function Item (a,b,c) {
    this.name = a;
    this.price = b;
    this.id = c;
}

function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    // Loop over the inventory array and tally up the total cost
    for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i ++) {
        total += inventory[i].price;
    }
    return total;
}

// We can store our item instances on an array
var inventory = [
    new Item ("Pen", 2.50,"001"),
    new Item ('Pencil', 1.25, '002'),
    new Item ('Paper', 0.75, '003')
];

console.log('Total is:', getTotal());
```